# Short story where people could live 'forever' by buying themselves new host-bodies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this sci-fi short story a while back - here's what I remember of the plot:

- People could live 'forever' by buying themselves new host-bodies for a certain amount of money (a million dollars, I think). For some reason everybody was rich or at least they could afford a host body every X or so years so virtually everybody lived forever.
- People are spending their lives learning new skills, like playing the piano, science, sports, etc...
- The protagonist lives many lives and becomes an expert at 'everything'; after a while he gets tired of 'living-to-learn' and decides to transfer his mind into the body of an infant (who never ages?), thereby living a life of complete ignorance (and bliss).

The story is part of a 3-story 'series' written by a not-so-famous American author. It was quoted in an article in the *New Yorker* - a couple of years ago, perhaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer... on this [scifi question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188805/harlan-ellison-story-about-immortality).

It is *Four Short Novels* by Joe Haldeman. There's also an audio version narrated by Harlan Ellison.